# Is it possible to send JSON object in HTTP GET request in android?

Tags: android

I have JSON object and I wanted to send it to server via HTTP get request form an android device. Is it possible to send JSON in HTTP get request?

Comment: um a GET request by specification is not allowed to have a request body. What do you want to send?

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually I wanted to achieve this my_url?data={"resolution_dtl":[{"votes":"2121.000","opid":"1","resid":"3"}],"evid":"11179"}

Comment: Why do you want to use HTTP GET? With HTTP POST you can achieve the same.

Comment: @JorgeE.Hernández, Because some API's not give whole response with `HttpPost`, If the API's made in get than post method.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a POST method to send your json objects to your server. You can also use this as a great example. [POST JSON from android device](http://localtone.blogspot.com/2009/07/post-json-using-android-and-httpclient.html)